# .splice is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I have this filter, and I have error filtered[i].splice is not a function

```
 .filter('tsFilter', function() {
  return function(model, filter) {
    var filtered = [];
    if (model != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        filtered[i] = model[i];
      }
    }        

    for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
      if (filtered[i].List.length == 0)
        filtered[i].splice(i, 1);
    }
    return filtered;
  };
})
```

Why I have this error? how to solve that?

Comment: Splice is a javascript function available for arrays.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Check the data of filtered[i]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have to update

```
for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
  if (filtered[i].List.length == 0)
    filtered.splice(i, 1);  //updated
}
```

Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to use:

```
for (i = 0; i < filtered.length; i++) {
  if (filtered[i].List.length == 0)
    filtered.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Although it is not a good idea to remove elements from the array that you are iterating over.

Comment: I know this is a old answer but would you mind saying why?